# NSContactsUsageDescription not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, abaddressbook

I am setting a string on my Info.plist file for NSContactsUsageDescription; but it is not showing up in the alert dialog that asks for permissions to access Contacts. Is there anything I am missing?

I have tried NSLocationUsageDescription and that one is working fine.

To get the Address Book Dialog I am using ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions and ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion. I am not sure if there is something additional I should be doing.

Comment: Deployment target = iOS6.0?

Comment: Is that a requirement? Need to support also iOS 5.0. NSLocationUsageDescription is also support from iOS 6.0+ and works fine in my case.

Comment: All of the UsageDescription entries only work on devices with iOS 6+. Try resetting the privacy settings on the device/simulator to be sure the prompt will appear again. Remember, it only appears once.

Comment: I have no problem showing the prompt, the only issue is with the description text not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

This is only supported iOS6.0 and up, as you can see from Apple's developer reference:

[image]

Comment: I understand that only ios6 devices will be able to see the message. I've been testing this on ios 6.0+. I can get NSLocationUsageDescription to show up, however no luck with NSContactsUsageDescription.

Comment: Could you post your info.plist? Can't really see why this is not working for you

Comment: Also, make sure that if you have multiple info.plist files, they are properly hooked up to their relative build settings

Comment: @Stavash how do you do that?

Comment: In your target build settings under "Packaging" there is a "Info.plist file" section where you can specify the path to the plist file.